# .NET Globalization when running App from VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When running an ASP.NET app from the VS (Visual Studio 2015), where is the web site set for the VS application.
That is, where would I see the .NET Globalization of the VS-site?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've written a "Globalized" application, and you want to test different values of language/locale, correct?

One easy way to do this is to run your app in MSVS and simply specify different values in your URL:

**Specifying alternate culture from URL (examples)**:

- German: https://localhost:44346/SubMenu?culture=de-DE&ui-culture=de-DE
- French: https://localhost:44346/SubMenu?culture=fr-FR&ui-culture=fr-FR

**Useful links for ASP.Net/MVC "Internationalization"**:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/internationalization-in-asp-net-core-mvc/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/best-practices-for-developing-world-ready-apps

PS:

If you're actually still using MSVS 2015 ... I'd strongly encourage you to upgrade.  Unless you have a very good reason not to.  I'm not sure you'll be able to target any current versions of ASP.Net Core/.Net 5.x/.Net 6.x with your current compiler...

Comment: Thank you for your message.  Yes, I am trying to simulate how the application (ASP.NET forms, not MVC) would display the data based on the Culture setting in the .NET Globalization of the site.  I can connect to a customer site but I don't want to mess it up.
This PC is Windows 7 and I am reluctant to use VS 2019 on it (in order not to break anything).
I will follow your links and see if they provide an approach.

Comment: OK: what you want to try is adding `culture=xy-z&ui-culture=abc-d` to your URL, and inspect the results in a browser.  It doesn't matter if the URL happens to be your customer's site (with your app), or your local workstation (with the app started from MSVS).  Please let us know what happens!

Comment: Based on your articles, I added the culture and uiCulture in the Globalization setting in web.config and it shows in the application.  This allows me to manipulate/change the value of the culture and see how the program works.  I find that this is a "cleaner" approach than adding it to the URL.
Thank you.

Comment: That's certainly a viable approach.  You can also change it programmatically.  Personally, I find typing the extra parameters in the URL the easiest/fastest/cleanest/most flexible method for testing multiple different languages/locales all at once.  But whatever works best for you :)  ALSO: whenever you migrate your app to .Net 5.x or higher ... you'll probably be using the (Json) app.config, instead of the old (XML) web.config.